# How do I programatically insert a new menu item?

Tags: plugin-development, menus

I'm developing a plugin and I want to insert menu items programmatically.

When my theme creates a menu, it uses this call:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) );
```

Which resulted in something like this in the HTML:

```
<div class="nav-menu"><ul>
     <li class="current_page_item"><a href="somewhere">menu-item-1</a></li>
     <li class="page_item page-item-107"><a href="somewhere-else">menu item 2</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

I want to be able to intercept this somehow and insert my own HTML programmatically before the closing `</ul>`. How do I hook it up?

Comment: A detail blog: http://goo.gl/TbxqDy

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Before being printed, all the menu items get run through a filter.  You can target the `wp_nav_menu_items` filter to tack things on to the menu:

```
// Filter wp_nav_menu() to add additional links and other output
function new_nav_menu_items($items) {
    $homelink = '<li class="home"><a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">' . __('Home') . '</a></li>';
    // add the home link to the end of the menu
    $items = $items . $homelink;
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items' );
```

Or, to be more specific, you can target only the desired menu by replacing the `add_filter` line from above with the following, and replacing `$menu->slug` with your menu's actual slug name:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items', 'new_nav_menu_items' );
```

[Source Tutorial](http://wpfirstaid.com/2010/10/extend-the-wordpress-menu/)

Comment: Thanks, but nothing happens. I even tried to put your code verbatim just before my theme's `wp_nav_menu` call, and still no effect.

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens? I just double-checked and a Home link is added as the first item in the menu. You must have a menu defined for the menu location and not be falling back to `wp_page_menu()`.  The code definitely works. Whether it answers your question or not is another matter because I couldn't really understand what you were asking.

Comment: I've edited the code to add the home link to the *end* of the menu, but the WordPress principle is still the same.

Comment: It didn't work because I didn't have a user defined menu. After I created my own menu, it works. Thanks

Comment: If you were asking how to add links to your menu, and this answered it, then you should accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `container` to `false` and use the `items_wrap` argument to omit the `ul`, then the function will only output the `li` tags, letting you wrap it in whatever you need.

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
        'container' => false
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it only changes
    <div class="nav-menu">...</div>
to
    <div class="menu">...</div>
So I still couldn't put my contents because wordpress already spits the end of the menu

Comment: you need to create a menu and assign it to your theme location, I'll guess you haven't done that. tested and working with latest WordPress and TwentyThirteen theme.

Comment: I'm using wordpress's theme (twentytwelve) and what I'm trying to do is to change the theme's top menu. So the menu appears in the final HTML with links to my pages as its menu items, but I need to put my own menu item programatically.

Comment: did you create a menu under `Appearance > Menus` and assign it to that theme location?

Comment: OK, now it works after I created a user-defined menu. Thanks a lot!